# npx react-native run-android failed after executing 99%

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to run a react-native app on my mobile but every time I run the command `npx react-native run-android` my build fails after executing up to 99% add it gives error saying:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.
InstallException: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl431548781.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #158): androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present
```

I dont know what causing this issue and I tried many things but nothing seems to working as given in the error 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED' so I guess it is related to manifest file so here is my manifest.xml file

```
  package="com.masjidapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


    <application
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      >

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I also tried to add 'android:exported="false"' or 'android:exported="true"'  in activity but still no use.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by deleting emulator  in android studio and then I create  new emulator by changing the option of  `quick boot` to `cool boot`.
coolboot mean when we start emulator they clear all previous data, In quick boot my emulator hang and they donot gave response to open App.